# How to count occurrences of a word in all the files of a directory?

Tags: linux, unix, count, find, grep

I’m trying to count a particular word occurrence in a whole directory. Is this possible?

Say for example there is a directory with 100 files all of whose files may have the word “aaa” in them. How would I count the number of “aaa” in all the files under that directory?

I tried something like:

```
 zegrep "xception" `find . -name '*auth*application*' | wc -l
```

But it’s not working.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`grep -roh aaa . | wc -w`

Grep recursively all files and directories in the current dir searching for aaa, and output only the matches, not the entire line. Then, just use `wc` to count how many words are there.

Comment: Also if you don't want the actual matches, only the count, you can use `grep -rcP '^aaa$' .` That saves you the piping and prevents getting embedded 'aaa'

Comment: @cgledezma good point about `-c`, but it fails if there are two or more occurrences of the searchString in one line.

Comment: MM... Indeed, I hadn't noticed it only counts the number of lines matched and not the actual number of matches. Still I think it may be useful to place the word boundaries to avoid nested matches. Sorry, I placed them incorrectly on the previous comment: `grep -rohP '\baaa\b . | wc -w`

Comment: @cgledezma sure, word boundaries may be useful in some situations

Comment: On osx @cgledezma's solution translates to `grep -rohe '\baaa\b . | wc -w` since `-P` is not available.

Comment: One thing to also note is if you search for a pattern that has a space in between multiple words or letters e.g  `grep -roh 'global \$' . ` or `grep -roh 'one two' .  ` then when piping to wc -w it will count all of the words.  So you may want to only count the number of exact matches not total of all the words in the result.  I achieved this by piping into grep again but searching for the first word only e.g `grep -roh 'global \$' . | grep -o 'global' | wc -w `.  However may be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 11):

Another solution based on `find` and `grep`.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -o aaa {} \; | wc -l
```

Should correctly handle filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: perfect! I was using find based on size, this works perfectly

Comment: @Fredrik : this executes perfectly but is there a way to the word count by avoiding multiple counts for that word in the same file? Eg : if word "aaa" appears in "file1.txt" 10 times, but count should increase only by 1 but not 10 & similarly in other files too within a directory.

Comment: @annunarcist -- yes it can be done. Post a new question and I`ll take a look :-)

Comment: @Fredrik : posted! Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869272/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-word-in-all-the-files-of-a-directory-but-with-cou)

Answer (score 9):

Use `grep` in its simplest way. Try `grep --help` for more info.

---

1. To get count of a word in a **particular file**:

   ```
   grep -c <word> <file_name>
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   grep -c 'aaa' abc_report.csv
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   445
   ```

---

2. To get count of a word in the **whole directory**:

   ```
   grep -c -R <word>
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   grep -c -R 'aaa'
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   abc_report.csv:445
   lmn_report.csv:129
   pqr_report.csv:445
   my_folder/xyz_report.csv:408
   ```

Answer (score 4):

### Let's use AWK!

```sh
$ function wordfrequency() { awk 'BEGIN { FS="[^a-zA-Z]+" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { word = tolower($i); words[word]++ } } END { for (w in words) printf("%3d %s\n", words[w], w) } ' | sort -rn; }
$ cat your_file.txt | wordfrequency
```

**This lists the frequency of each word occurring in the provided file.** If you want to see the occurrences of your word, you can just do this:

```sh
$ cat your_file.txt | wordfrequency | grep yourword
```

**To find occurrences of your word across all files in a directory (non-recursively), you can do this:**

```sh
$ cat * | wordfrequency | grep yourword
```

**To find occurrences of your word across all files in a directory (and it's sub-directories), you can do this:**

```sh
$ find . -type f | xargs cat | wordfrequency | grep yourword
```

*Source: [AWK-ward Ruby](http://tomayko.com/writings/awkward-ruby)*

Answer (score 1):

```
find .|xargs perl -p -e 's/ /\n'|xargs grep aaa|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

cat the files together and grep the output: `cat $(find /usr/share/doc/ -name '*.txt') | zegrep -ic '\<exception\>'`

if you want 'exceptional' to match, don't use the '\<' and '\>' around the word.

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with:

```
cat * | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep '^aaa$' | wc -l
```

as in the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat file1
this is a file number 1

pax$ cat file2
And this file is file number 2,
a slightly larger file

pax$ cat file[12] | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep 'file$' | wc -l
4
```

The `sed` converts spaces to newlines (you may want to include *other* space characters as well such as tabs, with `sed 's/[ \t]/\n/g'`). The `grep` just gets those lines that have the desired word, then the `wc` counts those lines for you.

Now there may be edge cases where this script doesn't work but it should be okay for the vast majority of situations.

If you wanted a whole *tree* (not just a single directory level), you can use somthing like:

```
( find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} ';' ) | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep '^aaa$' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a grep regex syntax for matching words only:

```
# based on Carlos Campderrós solution posted in this thread
man grep | less -p '\<'
grep -roh '\<aaa\>' . | wc -l
```

For a different word matching regex syntax see:

```
man re_format | less -p '\[\[:<:\]\]'
```