# How to count occurrences of a word in all the files of a directory? But with count incremented only once per word per file

Tags: linux, count, grep, find, cpu-word

This question is an additional constraint on this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135065/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-word-in-all-the-files-of-a-directory/6162253?noredirect=1#comment29554036_6162253). I wanted achieve the word count by avoiding multiple counts for that same word in the same file? Eg : if word "aaa" appears in "file1.txt" 10 times, but count should increase only by 1 but not 10 & so on for other files too within a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you want is the number of files that contain that word. Easy:

```
grep -l word *|wc -l
```

Comment: Exactly! It's working :) and to make it case sensitive and for exact word match(i.e., avoid nested matches), it would be : `grep -l "\bword\b" *|wc -l`, right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is already case-sensitive. Do you mean case-_insensitive_?

Comment: But if a directory has both directories and files within itself, this command applies only to the files in it but not its child directories recursively, right? Is there a way to count words in this scenario too?