# Code for the given question in shell script

Tags: sh

Write a shell script program to search for a keyword in all the files in current folder and display the count of occurrence in each file.

Comment: This really sounds like the text from an assignment. What exactly is your problem? Maybe have a look at the "grep" command.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so you should post what you tried.

Comment: If this is an interview question, or a question from an instructor, the correct answer is "what's a folder?", followed by standing up and walking out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking help for homework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count occurrences of a word in all the files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135065/how-to-count-occurrences-of-a-word-in-all-the-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the expected output, you may need to play around with `grep` options

Here's a possible solution:

`grep -o pattern *  | awk -F: '{a[$1]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}'`

**Explanation:**

Consider the search pattern to be string `abc`

I made the following ***assumptions***, as these are not explicitly stated in your question:

- Count multiple occurrences of the pattern for each line inside each file
- Count occurrences of pattern that could occur within a word and/or is surrounded by other characters
- Print file name and count in the output

I created the following ***test files*** in the same directory that you intend to run your search on:

1. `file1` with one occurrence of the pattern `abc` : expected count = 1

   ```
   cat > file1
   abc
   xyz
   ```
2. `file2` with multiple occurences of pattern `abc` in a single line : expected count = 2

   ```
   cat > file2
   abc abc
   xyz
   ```
3. `file3` with pattern embedded in a word / surrounded by other characters : expected count = 5

   ```
   cat > file3
   xabcyz
   xabcyabc
   123abc
   abc_
   ```

**Step 1**: 
Use `grep -o abc *` to generate the following output:

```
    file1:abc
    file2:abc
    file2:abc
    file3:abc
    file3:abc
    file3:abc
    file3:abc
    file3:abc
```

What does `-o` option do?

```
    -o, --only-matching
    Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, 
    with each such part on a separate output line.
```

`man grep` to explore more `grep` options..

**Step 2**: 

*(Note: Although this is not directly related to your question, I'm including an explanation on how the above output is aggregated to return counts)*

Consider output of Step 1 as an associative array `a` with the index being file1, file2 and so on
Pipe the output with `awk -F: '{a[$1]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}'`

In the awk command:

- Specify the field separator `F` as `:` as we're only interested in the first column (i.e index of the array)
- `a[$1]++` increments the count of the index as you traverse through the array
- `END{actions}` executes what you specify in `actions` before exiting
- `for (i in a)print i, a[i];` is a for loop that prints each index `i` from array `a` with the respective count `a[i]`

**Final output:**

```
    $ grep -o abc *  | awk -F: '{a[$1]++;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}'
    file1 1
    file2 2
    file3 5
```

Hope this helps.